# Get RRSIG value with powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to develop a PowerShell script to get DNS record for a particular website to a public DNS like Google’s 8.8.8 and look for RRSIG value. i can perform this with linux with below command and i dont know how to get into this with powershell. please could someone help on this.

Linux - dig @8.8.8.8 +dnssec xxx.xx.com

Thanks,
Dinith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for something like this

```
Resolve-DnsName xxx.xxx.com -Server 8.8.8.8 -dnssecok
```

Detail explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn593652(v=ws.11)

Comment: Glad to hear @diniththaruka